# Connection String to connect to mysql setup under Ubuntu in Amazon EC2

Tags: asp.net, mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, connection-string

Hihi, I have setup an Ubuntu instance in Amazon EC2, and I have setup MySQL under Ubuntu. Would like to ask, how can I connect my external asp.net application to this MySQL database? What should be the connection look like?

I am using Entity Framework 4. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have figured out the connection string format as follow:

```
<add name="ejabberdEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ejabberdDB.csdl|res://*/ejabberdDB.ssdl|res://*/ejabberdDB.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-x.amazonaws.com;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbpassword;database=ejabberdDB;Port=3306;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

:)